# error in multi-line equation

Tags: equations

I have this equation:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
t(E,T)&= \left[ A  \\
&\quad +B \right] ^{-1} \\
&\quad \ln\left(  C \right) 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

But it says that there is an error. This error because I put the end bracket (right one) in the second line. I need to keep it in the second line. Do you know some idea of solving this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to close `\left[` with `\right.` at the same line.

Comment: You can "close" with `\right.` and open with `\left.` but you should better use some fixed-height brackets. Normal `[ A` will do just fine, I guess.

Comment: as written you do not need left right at all, but if your real example expressions are taller use `\bigl[` on line 1 and `\bigr]` on line 2 (or `\Biggl` or whatever size you need. (This must be a duplicate)

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried all of your suggestions but non of them work correctly. I need the left bracket in 1st line, and the left bracket in the second line.